# What is the "Gizmo" central to the 3D viewport?

Tags: edit-mode

I have searched the manual but unsure what the 'gizmo' central to the 3d viewport is referred to as and what effect if has on the exported model. I was thinking it could be the central datum/ reference point. All I know is that in MSFS2020 if the model is placed above it it will be displayed 'floating' but what effect does it have if the model is placed right of it ie on the Y axis?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That "gizmo" is called the **3D cursor**. It has no effect on the final export - it is not "there". It's only a tool to use during modelling (New items are added at it's location, it is used as a pivot for the spin tool, etc...). One way to move it is to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> then <kbd>Right Click</kbd> to place it on the spot. Another way is to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> for more placement options.

More info on the **3D Cursor** here - https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/3d_cursor.html

Note - you mentioned in your question that items will be "floating" if placed above it- that is not the 3D cursor. The point which objects use as a central reference point is called the **Origin** - represented in your photo as a small, orange dot. You can change an objects position relative to it's own origin point by moving the whole object in *Edit Mode*.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. Is there a central datum or reference point for the model which would get exported with the model? The reason I ask is that in an airport editor for Microsoft Flight Simulator a 'footprint' is displayed where the user places 3d objects (on the edit screen) and each 'footprint' has a 'handle' displayed next top it for easy changing the orientation of the scenery object and someone (in MSFS forum) suggests that position of that handle relative to the footprint is controlled by the datum/reference point of the object.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the _origin point_ that I mention in the second part of my question. If I move an object way above its origin and then export it, in the new program (for example UE4) even though it will import the object with the origin at 0,0,0 in that world space, my exported model will be high up in the air.

Comment: Thanks again Christopher. I didn't see the last paragraph when I viewed it earlier so maybe added when you edited your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I attempted to move my object in edit mode but I was unable to select all the array objects only the original objects before the array modifier was added. Maybe this has to be done before adding modifiers?

Comment: The array effect disappears in edit mode - since all the array objects are copies of one thing, edit mode only shows you that one thing (for ease of modelling). You can still move it to your hearts content. Once you go back to Object mode, the array should be visible again as normal (however your offsets may be different depending on which ones you used. ) If this is the case, you will just have to readjust some values in the array modifier settings.

Comment: Thanks again. I experimented with a simple cube and exported for MSFS but that did not result in what I was hoping to achieve as it is considered (in the MSFS airporrt editor) as the 'fulcrum' of the entire model and so when positioned away from the model footprint causes all sorts of problems. Anyway I'll 'put this to bed'.